# About android:launchMode="singleInstance" compatibility

Tags: android

I have used `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in my application how compiled & run perfectly in android `api 2.3.3` but when i have deployed my application in the android OS which based in `api 4.0` ,the intent can't be launched in the background. What is the relation between android launchmode  and the version of android api ?

Comment: Hi. I'm having same issue, did you find any reason?

Comment: Hi ,i have tried with this code :       Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(context,com.entreprise.test.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: thanks, I solved it changing launchMode with singleTask

Comment: Hi ,i have tried with this code :       Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setClass(context,com.entreprise.test.class);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
      context.startActivity(intent);  and add android:launchMode="singleTask" that s work for display activity which turn in background (in API level 11 and ) but my probleme is i have service which be closed after open this last intent ,i hope find  solution for this problem and i will write him here

Comment: ok I'll be waiting for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have got it working. Following is the solution of my problem.

This is my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class BroadcastReceive extends BroadcastReceiver{
    // Display an alert that we've received a message.    
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Intent i = new Intent(context,CallActivity.class);
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And in `manifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".callActivity"
    android:label="@string/invite_activity_lbl"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It's compatible with API level 11 and more